# Convert a List of JSON-objects input into a nested Map

Tags: java, jackson, java-stream, collectors, nested-map

I have a String input in the following format:

**Input String:** `[{ "id":"1", "name":"A", "address":"St 1"},{ "id":"2", "name":"B", "address":"St 2"}, ...]`

And I want to be able to convert this to a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` format.
So, something like:

**Required Output Format:** `{1: {id:1, name:"A", address: "St 1"} 2: {id:2, name:"B", address: "St 2"}}`

I created a class to help in parsing the input:

```
public class Student{
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String address;
}
```

Which I am trying to do through Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to get the data in the format: `List<Student>` format and then use `Collectors.toMap()` to convert it to a Map of Maps format.

All the examples I have seen so far suggest an approach like:

```
List<Student> student = objectMapper.readValue(inputString, new TypeReference<List<Student>>(){});

Map<String, Student> studentTempMap = student.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Student::getId,
        Function.identity()
    ));
```

Which makes the `studentTempMap` something like:

```
{ 1: object of Student("id":"1", "name":"A", "address":"St 1"),
  2: object of Student("id":"2", "name":"B", "address":"St 2"), 
  ... }
```

A brute force approach from here:

1. create a new Map studentMap
2. Iterate over keys (which are "id") in studentTempMap.

   - Then create another Map, temp.
   - Add keys "id", "name", and "address" and values using something like `studentTempMap.get(2).get("id")`, and something similar for all the other keys (name and address). Where 2 would be the current iterator key over the Map `studentTempMap`.
   - Finally add a key say as 2 (current iterator) and value temp in the `studentMap`.

I do not want to use this brute force approach as I have a large number of `Student` objects.

Is there a way through `ObjectMapper` to get the output directly in the form of `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` format?
Or is there a way through `Collectors.toMap` to parse it to the above format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to convert this to a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`

If you want to obtain a *nested map of strings* `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` as a result, you don't need to convert JSON into a list of POJO.

Instead, you can parse JSON into a list of maps `List<Map<String,String>>` and then generate a *nested map*.

```
String inputString = """
    [{ "id":"1", "name":"A", "address":"St 1"},
     { "id":"2", "name":"B", "address":"St 2"}]""";
    
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, String>> students = objectMapper.readValue(
    inputString, new TypeReference<>() {}
);
        
Map<String, Map<String, String>> studentMapById = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        map -> map.get("id"), // key 
        Function.identity(),  // value
        (left, right) -> left // resolving duplicates
    ));
    
studentMapById.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
1 : {id=1, name=A, address=St 1}
2 : {id=2, name=B, address=St 2}
```

Comment: Great solution. But there is one compile time error in new TypeReference<> as cannot use '<>' with anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @girdhar There's no compilation error - I've tested this solution. And there's no issue with using diamond operator and anonymous classes.

Comment: Yes you are right, actually I am using JDK 1.8 and that's why I am getting this error. This change for anonymous classes has been done in JDK 1.9 onwards.
"Java 9 – Diamond operator enhancements"

Comment: @girdhar "I am using JDK 1.8" - you've missed a couple of LTS versions. Anyway, even with JDK 8 adding a type variable isn't a big deal.